# callback is not a function in sqlite

Tags: node.js, oop, sqlite, callback

i tried to make `class DATABASE` to create `db.run` to the reusable method to call for create update and delete in SQLite by the callback, 
here is my code

```
const db = new sqlite3.Database("database.db", err => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(`can;t connected tp database, status: ${err}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`gotcha, succesfully connect to the database`);
  }
});

class DATABASE {
  static run(sql, params = [], callback) {
    db.run(sql, params, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
        console.log(`something wrong with this ${sql}`);
        console.log(err);
        callback(err);
      } else {
        callback({"id" : this.lastID}) // this is could be null also
        console.log("sucesfully fo this ", sql);
      }
    });
  }
}

module.exports = DATABASE;
```

then i call that class by something like this:

```
const DATABASE = require("./setup.js");
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
const db = new sqlite3.Database("database.db", err => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(`can;t connected tp database, status: ${err}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`gotcha, succesfully connect to the database`);
  }
});

db.serialize(() => {
  const departement = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS departement(
                      id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                      name TEXT NOT NULL,
                      city TEXT
                      )`;

  const employee = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee(
                    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                    firstName TEXT NOT NULL,
                    lastName TEXT,
                    gender TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (gender IN ('Male', 'Female')),
                    email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE ,
                    phone TEXT,
                    dept_id INTEGER,
                    FOREIGN KEY (dept_id) REFERENCES departement(id)
                    )`;
  DATABASE.run(departement);
  DATABASE.run(employee);

  // , err => {
  //   if (err) throw new Erro(`bugs here`);
  //   else console.log("sucess.....");
  // });
});
```

you can see the else statement, `callback({this.lastID})` when i comment that and delete the else statement, it was successful to create the table,

but if I write that else statement again, the error message is CALLBACK IS NOT FUNCTION
but create table was successfully

the meaning this.lastId is **the way sqlite3 gives this info is it puts a field on the 'this' object within the context of the run(SQL, [params], function(err) { this.lastID }) callback function ... but, only for times when run is called with an INSERT statement. Otherwise, its just 0** as this tutorial said https://stackabuse.com/a-sqlite-tutorial-with-node-js/

did you think my callback is incorrect ??

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the way you have written `callback({this.lastID})` change it to `callback(this.lastID)` or `callback({"lastID" : this.lastID})`.

```
`const DATABASE = require("./setup");
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
const db = new sqlite3.Database("database.db", err => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(`can;t connected tp database, status: ${err}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`gotcha, succesfully connect to the database`);
  }
});
var abc= function(arg){
  console.log(arg);  
};

db.serialize(() => {
  const departement = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS departement(
                      id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                      name TEXT NOT NULL,
                      city TEXT
                      )`;

  const employee = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee(
                    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                    firstName TEXT NOT NULL,
                    lastName TEXT,
                    gender TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (gender IN ('Male', 'Female')),
                    email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE ,
                    phone TEXT,
                    dept_id INTEGER,
                    FOREIGN KEY (dept_id) REFERENCES departement(id)
                    )`;
  DATABASE.run(departement, abc);
  DATABASE.run(employee, abc);

  // , err => {
  //   if (err) throw new Erro(`bugs here`);
  //   else console.log("sucess.....");
  // });
});`
```

And you setup.js

```
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
const db = new sqlite3.Database("database.db", err => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(`can;t connected tp database, status: ${err}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`gotcha, succesfully connect to the database`);
  }
});

class DATABASE {
  static run(sql, callback) {
    db.run(sql, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
        console.log(`something wrong with this ${sql}`);
        console.log(err);
        callback(err);
      } else {
        callback(this.lastID) // this is could be null also
        console.log("sucesfully fo this ", sql);
      }
    });
  }
}

module.exports = DATABASE;
```

Comment: typo for the question, my callback was like this also : `callback({"lastID" : this.lastID})` 
but, didnt work :(